# Proof by Contradiction: $100$ Balls & $9$ Boxes

Tags: inequality, discrete-mathematics, optimization, discrete-optimization

> Show, by giving a proof by contradiction, that if $100$ balls are placed in nine boxes, some box contains 12 or more balls.

I would like to ask for a hint for this quesiton. Thank you.

Comment: If all boxes contain at most $11$ balls, what is the maximum number of balls in the boxes?

Comment: It would be 99, so this would then be a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

The statement of the problem contains a very big hint: *by giving a proof by contradiction*. That means assuming that the result is false and trying to derive a contradiction from that assumption. What would make the result false? There would have to be some way to distribute $100$ balls amongst nine boxes so that **no** box contained $12$ or more balls, i.e., so that **every** box contained at most $11$ balls. What can you then conclude about the total number of balls in the nine boxes?